# What is the real difference between for loop and while loop?

Tags: javascript, java, c++

What is the difference between `for` loop and `while` loop?

I am not asking about the syntax or how each loop works or do while is an exit controlled loop.

What I need to know is **there must be a reason for creating for loop and while loop if the process done is same, then there is no need for the other**, I am looking for that reason.

And don't include `do while`, I am talking about `while` although `do while` is a part of while.

Comment: A for loop can be transformed into a while loop, but not necessarily the other way round. The main difference is that it may be in some sense easier or more natural to think about certain logic as "do for each value" vs "while some condition is true". That's all. (You certainly don't *need* both - golang only has for loops, for example).

Comment: --For loop should be used when you have some kind of counter variable which needs to be incremented with every loop iterations. --while loop should be used when you have some conditional statement and loop should be continued till that conditions is true, as soon as that condition becomes false loop will get terminated.

Comment: There has been written books about these fundamental elements of programming. Simply put, `for` loops are specifically for running through a list of elements, while `while` is simply that: _do X while true_. Here is an article to get you started: [Link](http://cs-fundamentals.com/tech-interview/c/difference-between-for-and-while-loop.php)

Comment: For javascript, inside the engine, for loops are rewritten as while loops IIRC. But as many syntax choices in JS, it's just for programmer convenience.

Comment: A 'while' loop should be used while a condition is true (hence the name...). You can write 'while' loops that mimic 'for' loops, but this is just writing self-obfuscating code.  A 'for' loop should always have a fixed number of iterations. You can write 'for' loops that mimic 'while' loops, but again - this is just writing self-obfuscating code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` is just a **syntactic sugar** for while, if not to say both can be implemented with `goto` statement as well as many other language constructs.

The historical reason was to make your program code look more human readable.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for the C++ language:

Basically this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

can be written as this which is strictly equivalent but maybe somewhat less readable:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10)
{
   printf("%d\n", i);
   i++;
}
```

But the loop control variable can be declared in the `for` statement which gives pretty compact code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

But with `while` you cannot have the equivalent of this where the scope of the loop variable is restricted to the loop itself:

It would be something like this, which is illegal C++:

```
while (int i < 10)
{
   printf("%d\n", i);
   i++;
}
```

You could write this instead:

```
{
  int i = 0; while (i < 10)
  {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    i++;
  }
}
```

but as you can see it's cumbersome and not very readable.

BTW you could write the same `for` loop like this which is really ugly:

```
  int i = 0;    
startfor:
  if (!(i < 10)) goto endfor;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    i++;
  goto startfor;
endfor:
  ;
```

Comment: You can encapsulate while(){blahblah} in {} and get the same as for(int x..)

{
int i = 0;
while ( i < 10 ) {...}
}

Comment: @grapes you're right, edited. but your solution is cumbersome.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I am talking about - "for" is a syntactic sugar. You can avoid it in all forms, but your code will become ugly.

Answer (score 0):

1. For loop should be used when you have some kind of counter variable which needs to be incremented/decremented with every loop iterations. if you use while loop in this kind of requirement you will be using one extra line of code to increment/decrement the counter.
2. while loop should be used when you have some conditional statement and loop should be continued till that conditions is true, as soon as that condition becomes false loop will get terminated.
3. while loop can be used as replacement of for loop but for loop can't be used to replace while loop

Comment: _"for loop can't be used to replace while loop"_: are you sure?

Comment: At least in C++ `while (condition) { do_something(); }`  is strictly the same as  `for (; condition;) { do_something(); }`

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Yes, but that's a non-standard and all-around crappy use of a 'for' loop.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas I'mean that point 3 of tha answer is actually wrong